# Bundler in heroku looking for concurrent-ruby-1.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm having trouble trying to push to heroku a fresh new rails app: `git push heroku master`

```
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.0 in any of the sources
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
```

It's **true**, concurrent-ruby-1.1.0 doesn't exist, version 1.0.5 does. [concurrent-ruby-1.0.5](https://rubygems.org/gems/concurrent-ruby)

When i looked to my local **Gemfile.lock** , i can see a line `concurrent-ruby (1.1.0)`

I tried to uninstall Bundler, reinstall Bundler, remove Gemfile.lock. In my Gemfile file there is nothing related to concurrent-ruby.

I show you my Gemfile.lock , you can double check that there is several concurrent-ruby dependencies but just only one is -v 1.1.0 (witch doesn't exist on rubygems.org

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
    activerecord (5.2.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.1)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    archive-zip (0.11.0)
      io-like (~> 0.3.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    bootsnap (1.3.2)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.2)
    capybara (3.10.1)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.2)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (0.9.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    chromedriver-helper (2.1.0)
      archive-zip (~> 0.10)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.0)
    crass (1.0.4)
    erubi (1.7.1)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.25)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.1.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    io-like (0.3.0)
    jbuilder (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.3)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.1)
    mimemagic (0.3.2)
    mini_mime (1.0.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    msgpack (1.2.4)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    nio4r (2.3.1)
    nokogiri (1.8.5)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    pg (1.1.3)
    public_suffix (3.0.3)
    puma (3.12.0)
    rack (2.0.5)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.1)
      actioncable (= 5.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.1)
      activestorage (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    railties (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    regexp_parser (1.2.0)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (1.2.2)
    sass (3.6.0)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    selenium-webdriver (3.141.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.2)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.2.0)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.19)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.0)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15)
  chromedriver-helper
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rails (~> 5.2.1)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.1p57

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.1
```

Am I the only one with this issue ? Thank you for you help

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

To resolve this issue, add to your Gemfile this line:

> gem 'concurrent-ruby', '~> 1.0.5'

Then run `bundle update concurrent-ruby` , `git add`, `git push` then you are ready to deploy to Heroku.

Comment: you can try `bundle lock --update` it will resolve your app's dependencies and update Gemfile.lock accordingly 
https://bundler.io/v1.11/bundle_lock.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and to fix it I run a `bundle update` that updated on my local app to the version `concurrent-ruby (1.1.2)`.
I tested in local and after commit on git, deploy it with `git push heroku master:master` and it works now.

I post below the Gemfile.lock and the log of the deploy.
Good luck,
Marc

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
    activerecord (5.2.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.1)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    archive-zip (0.11.0)
      io-like (~> 0.3.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    bootsnap (1.3.2)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.2)
    capybara (3.10.1)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.2)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (0.9.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    chromedriver-helper (2.1.0)
      archive-zip (~> 0.10)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.2)
    crass (1.0.4)
    erubi (1.7.1)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.25)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.1.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    io-like (0.3.0)
    jbuilder (2.8.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.3)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.1)
    mimemagic (0.3.2)
    mini_mime (1.0.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    msgpack (1.2.4)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    nio4r (2.3.1)
    nokogiri (1.8.5)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    pg (1.1.3)
    public_suffix (3.0.3)
    puma (3.12.0)
    rack (2.0.6)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.1)
      actioncable (= 5.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.1)
      activestorage (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    railties (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    regexp_parser (1.2.0)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (1.2.2)
    sass (3.6.0)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    selenium-webdriver (3.141.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.2)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.13)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.2.0)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.19)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.0)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15)
  chromedriver-helper
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  pg
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rails (~> 5.2.1)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  sqlite3
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.1p57

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.2
```

Here below the log of the deploy:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 311 bytes | 311.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Using rake 12.3.1
remote:        Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.2
remote:        Using minitest 5.11.3
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using builder 3.2.3
remote:        Using erubi 1.7.1
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
remote:        Using crass 1.0.4
remote:        Fetching rack 2.0.6
remote:        Using nio4r 2.3.1
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.1
remote:        Using arel 9.0.0
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.2
remote:        Using msgpack 1.2.4
remote:        Using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using method_source 0.9.1
remote:        Using thor 0.20.0
remote:        Using ffi 1.9.25
remote:        Using multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Using pg 1.1.3
remote:        Using puma 3.12.0
remote:        Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.8
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.8.5
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.7.0
remote:        Using mail 2.7.1
remote:        Using marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Using bootsnap 1.3.2
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using uglifier 4.1.19
remote:        Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.2.0
remote:        Using loofah 2.2.3
remote:        Using sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
remote:        Using sass 3.6.0
remote:        Installing rack 2.0.6
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.2
remote:        Using i18n 1.1.1
remote:        Using activesupport 5.2.1
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.1
remote:        Using activemodel 5.2.1
remote:        Fetching jbuilder 2.8.0
remote:        Using activejob 5.2.1
remote:        Using actionview 5.2.1
remote:        Using activerecord 5.2.1
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.8.0
remote:        Using rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Using actionpack 5.2.1
remote:        Using actioncable 5.2.1
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.2.1
remote:        Using activestorage 5.2.1
remote:        Using railties 5.2.1
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Using rails 5.2.1
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.7
remote:        Bundle complete! 19 Gemfile dependencies, 61 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (3.58s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Removing rack (2.0.5)
remote:        Removing concurrent-ruby (1.1.1)
remote:        Removing jbuilder (2.7.0)
remote:        The latest bundler is 1.17.1, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler`
remote: -----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (1.10s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        You set your `config.active_storage.service` to :local in production.
remote:        If you are uploading files to this app, they will not persist after the app
remote:        is restarted, on one-off dynos, or if the app has multiple dynos.
remote:        Heroku applications have an ephemeral file system. To
remote:        persist uploaded files, please use a service such as S3 and update your Rails
remote:        configuration.
remote:        
remote:        For more information can be found in this article:
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku
remote:        
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        We detected that some binary dependencies required to
remote:        use all the preview features of Active Storage are not
remote:        present on this system.
remote:        
remote:        For more information please see:
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku
remote:        
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
remote:        We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 48.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v8
```

Comment: I resolve this problem by adding tot Gemfile this line:`gem 'concurrent-ruby', '~> 1.0.5'`

Then run `bundle update concurrent-ruby` ,` git add`, `git push` then you are ready to deploy to Heroku.
Thank you for your answer Marc. I edited my post.